# bootstrap-icons not showing in deployed angular app

Tags: angular, bootstrap-icons

I have an angular app that works correctly in my development environment but once deployed on IIS the bootstrap icons are not displayed.

I used the following command to install the package:

`npm i bootstrap-icons`

Here 's the relevant section of my angular.json file

```
       "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
            ],
```

Here's the relevant section of my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-validate-equal": "^6.0.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^15.0.1",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^15.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "stripe": "^11.10.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
```

When I run the app locally, here are the packages that I see

[image]

When I run it on IIS here's what I see:

[image]

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Open the website that you have deployed on IIS and check console logs on browser, might be some useful hints there.

Comment: I solved this issue by replacing bootstrap-icons with font-awesome